# Efficient checking of a property of a collection of objects which are packed in `std::pair`s

Tags: c++, stdvector, std-pair

Given a function which checks a `std::vector<foo>` of items for a property

```
bool SomeProperty(const std::vector<foo>& items){ /* ... */ }
```

and assuming that the items in question are packed inside a vector of pairs (as `first`s), what is the most efficient way to check for the property? Note that the property is one of a collection of items, not of its individual constituents (for example: linear independence of a set of functions).

Here's code which copies the elements from the pairs into a separate vector and then calls the function. **Is there a way to avoid copying the elments**?

```
/* Pairs, whose firsts are of interest */
std::vector<std::pair<foo, OtherType>> vec_of_pairs = MakePairs();

/* Copy first element from all pairs into std::vector<foo> and apply the check */
std::vector<foo> my_items;
for(const auto& pair : vec_of_pairs)
    my_items.push_back(pair.first);
if (SomeProperty(my_items)){ // .. continue code
```

*Addendum:* If in this case the copy cannot be avoided, could `SomeProperty` be designed better, to allow for its efficient application?

Comment: That's why iterators exist, to decouple algorithms and containers. Can you redefine `SomeProperty` function?

Comment: If you are really worried about copying the. Why not create vector of references See reference wrapper it might be of help. vector of  plain reference is not what I am suggesting here

Comment: @Daniel Langr Iterators and vector of references were the two ideas I had in mind. It's just nothing I had ready to use, so decided to ask. I guess I'll go for iterators, although references seem like a thing good to know about.

Answer (score 3):

If you can transform `SomeProperty` into:

```
template <typename Range>
bool SomeProperty(const Range& foos){ /* ... */ }
```

Then with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might do

```
std::vector<std::pair<foo, OtherType>> vec_of_pairs = MakePairs();
if (SomeProperty(vec_of_pairs | ranges::view::keys)) { // keys is a transformation to take .first
    // .. continue code 
}
```